# What does '$ mean in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to obtain the ASCII number of a character, so I have the following:

```
VAR="a"
NUM=$(printf "%d" "'$VAR")
echo $NUM
```

What does `'$` mean in this context? Can someone point me to a documentation to understand the syntax? I don't understand if its part of `$(...)` or `printf` or `bash`.

Comment: Try `printf "%d" "'a"` and see what happens

Comment: With bash's builtin printf, you can do `printf -v NUM "%d" "'$VAR"` without having to spawn a subshell.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `'` is part of the printf argument (see the Arguments section [here](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf)).

The `$` is part of regular shell expansion, so the `printf` arguments become `%d` and `'a`.

Finally, `$(...)` construct is [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution), which in this case means that `NUM` has its value set to the output of the `printf` function.

Comment: Before the single-quote becomes part of the argument `printf` gets, it's also important to note that, it itself is inside the double-quoted string, so it's just an ordinary character as far as the shell syntax is concerned. (It doesn't start a quoted string as it would if it weren't escaped or quoted itself.)

Answer (score 28):

`'$` doesn't mean anything special. With `%d` in `printf`, it tries to evaluate the argument as an integer expression. `'a` is taken to be the `char` `a`, or the integer 97. You'd get the same result even if you didn't use variable expansion:

```
$ printf %d\\n "'a'"
97
$ printf %d\\n "'0'"
48
$ printf %d\\n "'"$'\1'
1
```

From [the bash documentation on `printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-printf) (emphasis mine):

> Arguments to non-string format specifiers are treated as C language constants, except that a leading plus or minus sign is allowed, and **if the leading character is a single or double quote, the value is the ASCII value of the following character.**

Any characters left are ignored, as noted in the comments.

Comment: Do you want to add anything about the use of the _single_ single quote as opposed to balanced singled quotes? All your examples (except the last) use balanced quotes, but without comment.

Comment: Relevant text from the bash man page: "Arguments to **non-string format specifiers** are treated as C constants, except that a leading plus or minus  sign  is  allowed, and  **if  the leading character is a single or double quote, the value is the ASCII value of the following character**."

Comment: You have written an extra apostrophe after the letters in your first two examples. So the second argument of your first example should be `"'a"` and not `"'a'"`.  Any characters after the first letter are ignored, so you won't get an error if you add that extra apostrophe, but it's not correct.

Answer (score 12):

As already said, the `'$` doesn't mean anything special by itself. Your `"'$VAR"` gets expanded to `'a`, which will be passed as an argument to the `printf` utility.

Then come the interesting part -- an obscure, but standard feature of `printf` (the shell utility, not the function from the C language).

According to the SuSv4 [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) (emphasis mine):

> The argument operands [to `printf`] shall be treated as strings if the
>        corresponding conversion specifier is `b`, `c`, or `s`, and shall be
>        evaluated as if by the `strtod()` function if the corresponding
>        conversion specifier is `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G`.
>
> Otherwise [**e.g. if the conversion specifier is `d`**], they
>        shall be evaluated as unsuffixed C integer constants, as described
>        by the ISO C standard, with the following extensions:
>
> - A leading `<plus-sign>` or `<hyphen-minus>` shall be allowed.
> - **If the leading character is a *single-quote or double-quote*, the
>        value shall be the numeric value *in the underlying codeset* of the
>        character following the *single-quote or double-quote*.**
> - Suffixed integer constants may be allowed.

If your shell supports multibyte characters (as with UTF-8, the default on any modern system), that numeric value will be that of the complete character, not of its leading byte:

```
% printf '%d\n' '"á' "'é"
225
233
% printf 'U+%X\n' '"猫儿'
U+732B
```

Notice that that's not the "ASCII value" of the character -- the [description](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564957/what-does-mean-in-bash#comment1050572_564960) for the bash manpage is at best misleading.

However, bash (and most other shells but yash) are not standard conformant, because they will perform that translation even with float specifiers like `f` or `g`, which is in clear violation of the first paragraph above, which says that `strtod()` should be used in that case:

```
% bash --posix -c 'printf "%f\n" \"Q'
81.000000
```

Comment: Welcome, great answer:: and username.